# Want to have on button click

Tags: javascript, events, dom, mapquest

Hi I am trying to find the distance between 2 location on MapQuest. I have a function

```
MQA.EventUtil.observe(window, 'load', function()
```

This function is loaded on the page load but i want it to be on a button click. Can anybody suggest me what should i need to change to have it on a button click.

Answer (score 0):

May be

```
MQA.EventUtil.observe(document.getElementById('button_id'), 'click', function () {});
```

Answer (score 0):

replace the `MQA.EventUtil.observe(window, 'load', function () {`with a regular function.

```
        function drawMap() {
            var options = {
                elt: document.getElementById('map'),            // ID of map element on page
                zoom: 7,                                        // initial zoom level of the map
                latLng: { lat: 36.1866405, lng: -86.7852455 }     // center of map in latitude/longitude
            };
```

.
.
.

Then in the body:  `<input id="Button1" type="button" value="GO" onclick="drawMap()" />`

Don't forget to remove the ')'   at the end of the MQA.EventUtil.observe(